# regular expression match chinese character in vim

Tags: vi

`:%s/早上好/good morning/g`   can substitute `早上好` with  `good morning`,
but  `:%s/\(早上好\s+\)\+/good morning/g` can not substitute   `早上好  早上好`  with `good morning` .
How can i write the right regular expression in vim?

Comment: Your regex doesn't work because 早上好 早上好 doesn't have a space at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
%s_\(早上好\s*\)\+_good morning_gi
```

Comment: I'm surprised to have received a downvote, I even tested it to work!

Comment: I think using \s\= is safer since * would also match zero characters which are not only preceding characters, but also ranges or metacharacters or empty line. So I'd say use %s_(早上好\s\=)\+_good morning_gi in the non-magic format.